# grafana multi value query in timestream

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, grafana, amazon-timestream

i have some problems displaying my aws timestream data in grafana. I added as a global dashboard variable DevEUI with 3 different specific values. But when i am using the multivalue syntax ${DevEUI} in my query with more then one value i get everytime a error.

hope somebody can give me a hint.

Regards and thanks in advance

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are most probably having a list of values as the value of your multivalue Grafana variable, but you are still using the `=` operator in your query. Try `... and DevEUI IN ('${DevEUI}')`. Or maybe without the single quotes or the parantheses... the exact syntax depends on your Grafana variable.

But, this is just an educated guess, since I cannot see neither your database schema nor the definition of this Grafana variable (both of which are important details in a question like yours, for future reference).

Comment: Did this solution work?
I am facing issues even when using `IN`.

Comment: For example, when using `DevEUI IN ('${DevEUI}')`, the multi-value selections results in a query that has the following `WHERE` clause

`DevEUI IN ('{value1, value2}')`. 

However, we need `DevEUI IN ('value1', 'value2')`.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it for a multivalued string value:

`timestream_variable_name = ANY(VALUES ${grafana_variable_name:singlequote})`

You might have to adjust [the formatting Grafana applies](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/variables/advanced-variable-format-options/#raw) to the concatenated variable value it generates, depending on your data type.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is long after the original question but @alparius pointed me in the right direction so I wanted to update the fix for the problem Joe reported.
Use formatting to get the proper quotes/values when formatting your query. Something like this:

```
Select * from database where searchiterm IN (${Multi-Value_Variable:sqlstring})
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32964768)

Comment: But it does exactly answer the question - I know because I used this in a Grafana dashboard where the original answer does not work - maybe explain why this is not acceptable?